# Is there a `eq` operator in elasticsearch for int type?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a document whose has a field `saleAmount` which is long type defined in the index.
I'd like to find the document based on this field to equal to an input value but ES doesn't have `eq` operator. What I have to do is:

```
GET indexname/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "saleAmount": {"gte": 801, "lte": 801}
    }
  }
}
```

The above query works fine but it doesn't look great. I wonder what the best way to compare a number value in Elasticsearch?

Comment: The query you have is the right way to do an equal operation on a numeric value. "Doesn't look great" doesn't mean "doesn't perform well"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `term` query, below is the working example

Index sample data with default mapping as Elasticsearch creates `long` field for numeric data.

```
PUT <your-lasticsearch-index>/_doc/1 

{
    "price" : 801
}

PUT <your-lasticsearch-index>/_doc/2

{
    "price" : 802
}
```

Search query using term on `price` field.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {
            "price" : 801
        }
    }
}
```

Search result bring only one document with price `eq` to `801`.

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "number_eq",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "price": 801
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Waring : As mentioned by @Val in the comment, Numeric fields are not optimized for `terms` query, and for better performance we should always use `range` queries on numeric fields.**

Comment: It's generally [discouraged to use `term` queries on numeric fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use) because of the way numeric fields are stored in ES. `term` queries work well for `keyword` and numeric fields are well-suited for `range` queries.

Comment: @Val thanks for the disclaimer, Indeed its the case, and I just added another way but I agree and would add your comment as warning.